# Dividing a Wedge

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a wedge (some percentage of a circle, less than 50% in my case), is there a way to easily divide it into 3 (roughly) equal areas? I'm thinking some subset/simplification of Euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can not trisect the angle with just a straightedge and compass. The proof of this utilizes Galois theory(or some abstract algebra).

There are [other ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Other_methods) to trisect an angle if you allow other tools.